# Hibernate unexpected result when using join tables with same column name (without alias)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 3.2.6-GA, hibernate-core 3.3.2-GA.

I have the following data

```
TABLE_A :               TABLE_ B:

B1 | B2                 ID | CODE
-------                 ---------
1  | 2                   1 | AAA
                         2 | BBB
```

I would like to **understand** why the following **SQL Query managed by Hibernate**

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("SELECT ");
sb.append(" b1.CODE, ");
sb.append(" b2.CODE ");
sb.append("FROM TABLE_A a ");
sb.append(" JOIN TABLE_B b1 ON b1.id = a.B1 ");
sb.append(" JOIN TABLE_B b2 ON b2.id = a.B2 ");

Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sb.toString());

List<Object> results = query.list();
```

return the following result:

```
 [[AAA, AAA]]
```

Whereas when I use **SQL aliases** :

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("SELECT ");
sb.append(" b1.CODE as code1, "); // here is the difference
sb.append(" b2.CODE as code2 ");
sb.append("FROM TABLE_A a ");
sb.append(" JOIN TABLE_B b1 ON b1.id = a.B1 ");
sb.append(" JOIN TABLE_B b2 ON b2.id = a.B2 ");

Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sb.toString());

List<Object> results = query.list();
```

return the following result:

```
 [[AAA, BBB]]
```

Comment: Is your query raw, or are you attempting HQL?  What is your underlying database?  Can you show the relevant Java code?

Comment: This is totally raw SQL, called with `getSession().createSQLQuery(...);`

Comment: Which version of Hibernate you use? Please, add the code with a query — with processing results.

Comment: I wouldn't normally expect this behavior.  Are you certain that the state of the database tables is identical before running each of the two queries?

Comment: Totally sure, I triple checked and can reproduce both of them now.